# QuartzServer not in Nuget download

Tags: quartz.net

I've been investigation Quartz.Net and reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726017/windows-service-started-and-then-stopped-using-topshelf) question on StackOverflow, as well as the code base [here](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet)

I've downloaded the Nuget Packages Quartz by Marko Lahma, v2.3.3, and it does not contain this the QuartzServer class, yet it exists in GitHub.  I'm looking for a complete example using the features of Quartz.Net, as they are defined [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/features.html), as [this](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/index.html) page is blank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See response on "Quartz.Server is not included into Nuget package" [issue](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/394):

> Traditionally the server binary has been only part of the zip package and not in NuGet. So need to address this somehow before final v3.
>
> Probably easiest to build yourself for now. Many want to customize the server any beyond the base template.

Comment: The file mentioned zip file can be downloaded from sourceforge downloads: https://sourceforge.net/projects/quartznet/files/quartznet/ . This might change to be hosted on GitHub releases page.